# How to make the background scroll along with the page?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and need help on how to make the background scroll along with the page so that the background is constant and is not repeated like default.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `fixed` and / or `absolute` positions in CSS. If you have any code, please provide to go further in the answer. But generally this may suit your basic usage:

**Markup**

```
<body>
    <div class="bg">
    <div class="wrapper">
         // other stuff here
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg{
    background-image: url( 'path/to/bg/file.jpg' );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

**Note**

Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the community to improve ur SOF experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your `html` body

```
body {
background-image:url('your image path') no-repeat;
position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have add the background image on body the just use this css

```
body{
    background-image: url( 'your_img_url' );
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
 }
```